# What are the exact programming instructions that are in user space?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel

I know that a process switches between user mode and kernel mode for running. I am confused that for every line of code, we should possibly need the kernel. Below is the example, could I get explanation of the kernels role in execution of the following coding lines. Does the following actually require kernel mode.

if(a < 0)
a++

Comment: The program only switches to the kernel when calling a kernel function. As in syscalls in linux.

Answer (score 6):

> I am confused that for every line of code, we should possibly need the kernel.

Most code in user-space is executed without the kernel being involved. The kernel becomes involved (and the CPU switches from user-space to kernel) when:

a) The user-space code explicitly asks the kernel to do something (calls a system call).

b) There's an IRQ (from a device) that interrupts user-space code.

c) The kernel is providing some functionality that user-space code is unaware of. The most common reason is virtual memory management; but debugging and profiling are other reasons.

d) Asynchronous notifications (e.g. something causing a switch to kernel so that kernel can redirect the program to a suitable signal handler).

e) The user-space code does something illegal (crashes).

> Does the following actually require kernel mode.

That code (`if(a < 0) a++;`) probably won't require kernel's assistance; but it possibly might. For example, if the variable `a` is in memory that was previously sent to swap space, then any attempt to access `a` is a request for the kernel to fetch that data from swap space. In a similar way, if the executable file was memory mapped but not loaded yet (a common optimization to improve program startup time), then attempting to execute any instruction (regardless of what the instruction is) could ask the kernel to fetch the code from the executable file on disk.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:
It depends on what you are trying to do, following code depending on which enviroment and how its compiled it shouldn't need to use the kernel.  The CPU executes machine code directly, only trapping to the kernel on instructions like `syscall`, or on faults like page-fault or an interrupt.

The ISA is designed so that a kernel can set up the page tables in a way that stops user-space from taking over the machine, even though the CPU is fetching bytes of its machine code directly.  This is how user-space code can run just as efficiently when it's just operating on its own data, doing pure computation not hardware access.

---

Long answer:
Comparing something and increasing value of something shouldn't require use of a kernel, On x86 (64 bit) architecture following could be represented like this (in NASM syntax):

```
; a is in RAX, perhaps a return value from some earlier function

 cmp rax, 0       ; if (a<0) implemented as
 jnl no_increase  ; a jump over the inc if a is Not Less-than 0
 inc rax
 no_increase:
```

Actual compilers do it branchlessly, with various tricks as you can see on [the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/T1rYrsco1).

---

Clearly there aren't any syscalls so this piece of code can be ran on any x86 device but it wouldn't be meaningful
What requires kernels are the system calls now sys calls aren't required to have a device that can output something in theory you can output something by finding a memory location that let's say corresponds to video memory and you can manipulate pixels to output something in the screen but for userland this isn't possible due virtual memory.

A userspace application needs a kernel to exist if a kernel did not exist then userspace wouldn't exist :) and please note not every kernel let's a userspace.

So only doing something like:

```
write(open(stdout, _O_RDWR), "windows sucks linux rocks", 24);
```

would obviously require a kernel.

Writing / reading to arbitary memory location for example: 0xB8000 to manipulate video memory doesn't need a kernel.

TL:DR; For example code you provided it needs a kernel to be in userspace but can be written in a system where userspace and kernel doesn't exist at all and work perfectly fine (eg: microcontrollers)

In simpler words: It doesn't require a kernel to be work since it doesn't use any system calls, but for meaningful operation in a modern operating system it would atleast require a exit syscall to exit with a code otherwise you will see Segmentation fault even though there isn't dynamic allocation done by you.

Comment: `jb increase` ; `increase:` is a no-op, it will either jump or fall-through to the same place.  You need to jump *over* the `inc`.  Also, if `a` was unsigned, `a<0` would be a compile-time constant `false`.  So you should be doing `jge skip_inc`, signed greater-or-equal.  https://godbolt.org/z/T1rYrsco1 shows various compilers; GCC `-Og -fno-peephole` actually uses a branch on `js`, jump if sign-flag is set.  Otherwise gcc/clang/msvc use various branchless ways, like cmp/sbb, or right shifting to get the sign bit as a 0 or 1, or test/lea/cmov.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the code we write is but obvious in the realm of user mode.. Kernel mode is only going to be in picture when you write any code that performs any system call..

and since the `if()` is not calling any system function it's not going to be in kernel mode.